# Wait for Asynchronous javascript function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I've seen similar questions asked regarding this problem. I'm pretty new to javascript and I couldn't figure it out.

I have a function which calls another function.

sayHello() has an async call.

```
var hello_message = null;

function invokeSayHello(msg) {
    sayHello(msg);
    //next action
    return hello_message;
} 

function sayHello(msg) {
    // simulate async call 
    setTimeout(function(){hello_message = msg + " World";},1000);
}
```

In this case hello_message is returned as null. How would I wait for that async call to complete before the next action line executes in invokeSayHello() function so the returned hello_message would not be null.

I think I'm supposed to use a callback but not sure how to do it.. Also, I call invokeSayHello() from a java file using executeScript()/Selenium

Appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the result **inside** the callback. You cannot/should not wait for the asynchronous function to complete. The asynchronous pattern assumes that you use the callback.

Like this:

```
function invokeSayHello(msg) {
    sayHello(msg);
} 

function sayHello(msg) {
    // simulate async call 
    setTimeout(function(){
        var hello_message = msg + " World";

        // Here you can process the result, like alerting it for example or
        // passing it to another function
        alert(hello_message);
    }, 1000);
}
```

So basically in asynchronous programming you forget about the keyword **return** and start passing callbacks to your javascript functions so that the caller can subscribe to those callbacks and whatever he wanted to do with the results inside the callback..

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. What if I had other statements instead of returning a value? I need to figure out a way to wait until that async call completes before //next action line executes.

Comment: You write those statements **INSIDE** the callback and not after the function call.

Comment: The driver program I use is written in Java. I have 2 seperate .js files. invokeSayHello() is in the wrapper.js and it calls sayHello() in api.js. The java driver calls the functions in wrapper.js. I also have get() methods in the wrapper file which I execute from the java driver. If I don't put a Thread.sleep between those two calls, my test fails.  Am I approaching this problem the wrong way ?

Comment: I am not sure what test you are talking about and what does Java has to do with javascript but in javascript when you use asynchronous functions nobody should be sleeping. You don't even have threads in javascript.

Comment: Maybe this would be a better explanation: I call these methods from a Java program, which I test the values of assigned variables. By the time sayHello() finishes executing, my Java driver keeps executing the next line, which is some getOutput() method. If I don't put a Thread.sleep between sayHello() and getOutput(), my test case fails, because getOutput is executed before a value assigned to the hello_message variable. How do I solve this problem? Is there a way I can take care of this using a feature in Selenium ? Thanks.

Comment: I still don't understand what `Java` has to do with your question. But once again in javascript there are no such concepts as thread.sleep as you have in Java.

Comment: I do this for testing purposes. I write test case in Java and call these methods in Javascript using executeScript and retrieve the output.

Comment: You shouldn't be using asynchronous javascript functions in this case.

Comment: The API I'm testing has asynchronous calls and the test cases are written in Java. I need to find a way to wait until those calls are completed.